# how to change the highlighted color of tab bar in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-theme

i want to change the highlight colour of Tab Bar. I will also use the Android Action Bar Style Generator to change the color but its not changing.

**Style.xml**

```
<resources>

<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">

  <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>

</style>

 <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
     <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

**tab_indicator_ab_example**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_example" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_example" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />
</selector>
```

Plz guide me to change the highlighted color of tab bar

Answer (score 3):

I have done with this code into my app. Now you can easily put this code to your app and I hopw this works fine for you.

Please put this below file to your drawable folder ans set this file as your background.

tab_bg_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/tab_normal"/>

</selector>
```

Put this code to your res -> values -> color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name = "tab_normal"> #FF0000 </color>
<color name = "tab_selected"> #000000 </color>
</resources>
```

Comment: its giving error No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@color/tab normal'). tab_bg_selector.xml

Comment: Please insert this file to your res --> values --> color.xml, not to your drawable folder. I've edited the above color.xml file, please put this file to the above path. I am 100% sure this will work fine for you.

Comment: color is not changing after inserting the color.xml in value folder

Answer (score 0):

try to use http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/ this is easiest way..

1) Use the UI to select colors for different items
   2) Once done click on "DOWNLOAD .ZIP"
   3)The ZIP file contains resource files that you have to copy in your project res/layout and res/drawableXXXX folders